# Setting httpd to be accessible through network

Tags: linux, httpd, fedora

I have set up my httpd and it's running. My problem is when I access my ip to another pc (my ip 192.168.1.234), I get only a response something like Not Avaible. did I miss something? when it its os was ubuntu, it was working fine

Comment: Are you using Fedora Server, Fedora Workstation, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

2 possibilities:

- Check the binding address of the htttpd.conf, if it is pointing to 127.0.0.1, this restricts access only via localhost. You can change to 0.0.0.0 to bind on all addresses.
- Check your iptables for possible firewall restrictions. This very common problem in desktop general use linux, like openSUSE.